# Need to reference String JavaBean from XML Definition of Hibernate SessionFactory

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-bean

I have a java bean that creates an endpoint:

```
@Bean
public String endpoint() {
    return "jdbc" + "a" + "b" + "c";
}
```

And I want to use that endpoint in my SessionFactory Bean:

```
<bean id="SessionFactory"
          class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean"
          parent="AbstractSessionFactory">
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.connection.url">endpoint</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

How do I wire this up so that I can use it this way?

Comment: Any restriction on defining _SessionFactory_? Mean, are you allowed to use _SessionFactory_  configuration in _java_ file rather then _xml_ file?

Comment: I wish; that would make this all much easier. It needs to stay in XML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It isn't ideal but using "map" instead of "props" I was able to get this to work. You can see full details at the link at the bottom, but my new code is:

```
@Bean
public String endpoint() {
    return "jdbc" + "a" + "b" + "c";
}

<bean id="SessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean"
      parent="AbstractSessionFactory">
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <map>
            <entry>
                <key>
                    <value>hibernate.connection.url</value>
                </key>
                <ref bean="endpoint"/>
            </entry>            
        </map>
    </property>
</bean>
```

http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/container/55849-referencing-collections-props